# offsite dns while having a local domain controller per organization branch

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, local

Is it possible with a reliable wan to have the centralized dns offsite and the domain controller for an organization hosted locally?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean `centralized dns offsite`?